# Best move for black

Tags: knight-endgame

```
[FEN "8/R7/4k3/3nP3/3p4/P2K4/1P6/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

What is the best move for black?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Chess SE! In order to help you, it would be useful to know your thought process, what are your ideas and what's your analysis of the position.

Answer (score 5):

At tournament level, Black can safely resign. If you wanna play some more moves, taking a pawn with 1...Kxe5 looks reasonnable.

I see no trick with stalemate nor with the d-pawn, e.g. 1...Nf4 2.Ke4 [2.Kxd4+-] d3 3.Kxf4 d2 doesn't promote because of 4.Ra6+ Ke7 5.Rd6 +-

1...Ne7 can be a trap [2.Kxd4?? Nc6+ with a probable draw (or not even, see Annatar's comment)] but it is easily beaten by 2.Ra6, 2.b4 or the simple 2.Rxe7.

Comment: 1...Kxe5 can be answered by 2. Ra5, forcing the exchange into a 100% won pawn endgame (two connected passed pawns & Black cannot defend d4 either). Even 1...Ne7 2. Kxd4 Nc6+ still looks won for White, after 3. Kc5 Nxa7 4. Kb6 etc. Black's king is in an inferior position and his knight will have trouble stopping both pawns all on his own. So yeah, you are right, Black should just resign.

Comment: @Annatar : Yes, 2.Ra5 is the simplest path among dozen of them toward the full point. Analysing the endgame after 1...Ne7 2. Kxd4 Nc6+ would be more interesting, White sure have nice winning chances.

Comment: I put this into Stockfish and it turns out that, unfortunately, Black still has no hope left after the fork. 1...Ne7 2. Kxd4 Nc6+ 3. Kc5 Nxa7 4. Kb6 Nc8 (forced) 5. Kc7 Na7 6. a4! and now the knight is trapped, White will play Kb7 next move. 6...Kd5 7. e6! ; and after 5...Ne7 the knight is too far away to stop both pawns.

Comment: It goes to show how screwed Black is if even after winning White's rook for a pawn, he still loses.

Comment: According to the Lomonosov tablebases, White mates in 23, after 1. ... Ne7 2. Kxd4 Nc6+, starting with 3. Kc5. Although oddly enough, when setting up the position initially, I had left the king on d4 and put the knight on a7, and it was shown as a draw.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your opponent is really, really weak (and presumably you are even weaker since you've got a completely lost position) then "resigns" is the best move.

If you want to see if your opponent knows how to win the position then you could try Kxe5 when black will play Ra5, pinning the knight, exchange off the knight and then push the a and b pawns and queen one of them. Other moves by you are equally futile.

If your opponent was good enough to get this completely won position then he is probably also good enough to know that he just needs to exchange his rook for your knight to have a trivial win and there is little you can do to stop this.

Comment: I believe you. Honestly, exchanging knight for rook would put black in more jeopardy as there's nothing left. Thanks anyway!